# Label a group of radio buttons with legend - need to wrap in fieldset?

Tags: html

I have a group of radio inputs. I need to label the entire lot. So I have used legend:

```
<input type="text">
....
<legend>Gender:</legend>
<input type="radio" value="m"><label>Male</label>
<input type="radio" value="f"><label>Female</label>
....
<input type="text">
```

My question is, do I need to wrap the above in a `fieldset` for `legend` to be valid? Also would wrapping it in a `fieldset` be better practice for screen readers?

Comment: In my opinion, I always group inputs in fieldSets, it keeps order. For finall user should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for;

```html
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Gender:</legend>
  <input type="text">
<legend>Gender:</legend>
<input type="radio" name="genVal" value="m"><label>Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="genVal" value="f"><label>Female</label>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

The answer to the your question is yes, you do need to tell the webpage what the legend is for, so you have to place the feildset. Additionally, I tested your code and  the radio buttons did not work, so I fixed them.

Comment: Yes, I use www.w3schools.com for web development